# Jspx Eclipse debug breakpoint not working in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jsf, breakpoints

I want to migrate from Oracle WebLogic to Apache Tomcat. So, Oracle WebLogic 10.3.6 changed to Apache Tomcat 9.0.x . I founded break point not work at tomcat and eclipse specific JSPs. All of source working good in Oracle WebLogic and Eclipse IDE. Break point working source:

```xml
<%
  System.out.println("breaking point"); // Break point working in Eclipse IDE.
%>
```

Break point not working source:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" version="2.3">
 <jsp:directive.page extends="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" />
 <jsp:declaration><![CDATA[//
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
       System.out.println("hello doGet"); // Break point not working in Eclipse IDE.
    }

 //]]></jsp:declaration>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: This may require a bug report with JDT Debugging, as I'm not sure what's going on. I can see that Tomcat 9.0.41 does create the needed SMAP in the resulting .class file for this example, and that the editor is setting the breakpoint as usual, but as you say the breakpoint isn't hitting as it should. There is an improvement to the editor plug-in that can be made to better match the generated Java class name, but even when made it doesn't solve the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Apache Tomcat is too new. Need use old version. Check JSP specification version. These code has no problem in migrating process, if you choose correct Apache Tomcat version (should be version Apache Tomcat 6.x or 7.x) + JDK version (should be 1.7).

Related documents

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18840/install_config_10_3_6.htm#EOHWL189
- https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/how-to-migrate-your-weblogic-or-websphere-app-to-tomcat/
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnajw/index.html

Let's tell me the result.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i can't do that.  cause  must migrate to jdk 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Do Nhu Vy

i must migrate from jdk 1.6 to jdk 1.8 now.

I happened to find a solution.

it need a line break with 'jsp:declaration' and '<![CDATA[//'

when i execute auto formatting then line break disappear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" version="2.3">
 <jsp:directive.page extends="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" />
 <jsp:declaration> <!-- here insert line break-->
   <![CDATA[//
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
       System.out.println("hello doGet"); // Break point not working in Eclipse IDE.
    }

 //]]>
   </jsp:declaration>
</jsp:root>
```